# putfield order of arguments

Tags: java, bytecode

In java bytecode "putfield" instruction  expects the top of the stack to be a value, and the top-1 of the stack to be a reference. Why is it not the other way round ?

It was asked in my lecture notes and I cannot find the answer.

Comment: Do you see any reason why it should be the other way round?

Comment: @BrunoReis since putfield knows about the size of the value to be stored, It should not really matter which argument is at which position as long as it is done in a consistent way? I thought this was something like calling conventions of assembly but I was not completely sure about the answer. Any reason why one approach is more secure than the other?

Comment: it seems to me that this has to do something with the way the AST the bytecode is constructed and traversed. not sure though. i am just shooting in the dark.

Comment: @vijay That sounds reasonable. Do you think it would be possible to design the AST such that parameters are the other way around?

Comment: @OsamaJaved yes, i think so. again, it seems that the instructions loading the parameters would be children to the `PUTFIELD` instruction itself. These instructions could be `ALOAD` and `ILOAD` for instance. so if one were to change the order in which they were traversed, the `ALOAD` could come after `ILOAD`. But again, this might have far reaching consequences on the other elements of the AST, its construction and parsing itself, especially if you want to keep the logic for each opcode consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order doesn't actually matter, since the VM and compiler could be implemented just as easily either way. But Sun chose to have the lower arguments appear lower on the stack.

You can see this not only with `putfield`, but with many other instructions, such as array loading and storing and method invocation. They all obey the same convention. The only explanation I can think of is that it is more intuitive this way.

If you read out the stack from bottom to top as left to right, then the arguments on the stack will have the same order as the arguments do in the method signatures or original source code. If you wanted to do it the other way, programmers would have to mentally treat the stack as reversed, which isn't a big deal, but possibly less intuitive.